# Deleted Ubuntu partition from windows 10 and Ubuntu dual system

Tags: microsoft-windows, ubuntu

After deleted  the Ubuntu partition and restarted computer, I got this message:
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else’s tab lists possible device or file completions.

Comment: Please help me, what should I do

Comment: https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-windows-mbr-from-ubuntu/ - you need a live usb with ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to restore your Windows 10 bootloader.

1. Create a bootable usb with a Win10 iso.
2. Start as you'll going to reinstall.
3. Enter troubleshooting.
4. Enter Windows Console.
5. Type `bootsect /nt60 drive_letter: /mbr`, where 'drive_letter' is the letter of the partition where your windows is installed.
6. Reboot.

*If step 5 fails, try adding `/force` to it.

This should solve the problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have resolved the problem. Thank you for your advise!

Answer (score 0):

To boot Windows 10 you need to fix your Windows 10 bootloader. Possible solution: reinstall Windows 10 from installation media (details [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4000735/windows-10-reinstall)). To keep all your personal apps, files and preferences, select `Custom install` > `Keep Everything` during installation.